# Get hour in current timezone from unix time

Tags: java, android, unix, calendar, timezone

I am trying to retrieve a converted "hour" integer for a user's time zone with GMT unix time. My code works SOME of the time, though, for example, it was 9:00 pm on the East Coast and getting a 0 for the hour. Can anyone help?

```
long l = Long.parseLong(oslist.get(position).get("hour"));

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(l);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(l * 1000);
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
Log.v("TIME:", ""+hour);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the time zone - it's default by default, as it were. And calling `setTimeInMillis` twice is pointless. So just:

```
Calendar calendar = calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(unixTimestamp * 1000L);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

... should be absolutely fine. If it's not, then going via string representations as suggested by other answers isn't going to help.

If that's giving 0 when it's 9pm on the East Coast, that suggests the default time zone is not one representing the East Coast. I suggest you diagnose that first:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
// Just in case the ID is misleading, what's the standard offset for this zone?
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted this API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

**Solution using `java.time` API:**

You can use [`Instant#ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) to get the `Instant` corresponding to your given Unix timestamp. Next, convert the `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime` at the required timezone and then you can get individual time units (e.g. hour) out of this `ZonedDateTime`.

```
// e.g. a Unix timestamp representing 9:00pm on 10-Sep-2023 in New York
long epochSeconds = 1694394000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds);
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(zdt);
System.out.println(zdt.getHour());
```

**Output:**

```
2023-09-10T21:00-04:00[America/New_York]
21
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/fk0BYz)

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you need the timezone itself, see [Class SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Specifically the `z` and `Z` formats.

Comment: You don't need to use `SimpleDateFormat` if the aim isn't to get a string representation. (And there's nothing in the OP's question suggesting they *do* want to convert to a string.)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
long l = Long.parseLong(oslist.get(position).get("hour"));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(l);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(l * 1000);
    Date date = calendar.getTime(); //current date and time in UTC
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH"); //HH = 0-23 hours
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); //format in given timezone

    String hourStringValue = df.format(date);
    int hourIntValue = Integer.parseInt(hourStringValue);
```

Comment: Formatting to a string and then parsing is a terrible way to approach this. `Calendar` is fine.

Comment: I did not know that Calendar by default convert the time to the current timezone. Thanks for the suggestion